# I am getting file not found error in watson notebook while the file already exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, csv, file

[This image contains an error in which I am getting file not found error while file already exists.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTiA7.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. It's not easy for people to debug unless they can copy your code and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just use forward slash('/') instead of backslash('')

```
path = 'C:/smthing/smthing.csv'
pd.read_csv(path)
```